# How to access configuration utility on PowerEdge 2850?

Tags: hard-drive

I am running PowerEdge 2850.
I want to launch PERC/CERC BIOS Configuration Utility ( [as on here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/step-by-step-guide-to-configure-hardware-raid-on-dell-servers-with-screenshots/)) when I reboot by pressing `CTRL+M` but I never succeed to get access to the configuration utility.
Is there an other way to access the configuration utility ?
(I must access to it to set my HDDs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an AZERTY keyboard. So I had to press on the button located on the right of 'N' letter to produce 'M'. This is because before the start of the operating system, the BIOS sets the keyboard to QWERTY by default.